# C# Saving to Excel issue

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# application that exports data to Excel. I have Excel 2010 and VS 2012 on my machine and am using .Net 4.5.

I quietly export in the background with Excel hidden from the user and then save it and launch it using Process.Start, but when I do this, Excel tells me that it can't open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid.

Here is my code:

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook myWBk;
myWBk = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(1);

// Some code to dump data to Excel

string sFilename = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\LHGR.xlsx";
myWBk.SaveAs(sFilename, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
myWBk.Close();
Process.Start(sFilename);
```

I have tried using the ".xls" extension, but then it saves it as an Excel 97-2003 format (which I can open) but it warns me that it is limiting the columns to 256 - I have more than that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't use the Excel interop for stuff like this, use the [Open XML SDK for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) instead.

Comment: As you can see in the duplicate, you're using the wrong `XlFileFormat`.

Comment: `WB.SaveAs(fileName, (int)Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, AccessMode: Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);` works for me.

Comment: In addition to what @ScottChamberlain advises, you may also want to look at the EPPlus Open Source project that takes a lot of the problems away for dealing with Excel.

Comment: Thank you guys. @Axel - your parameters worked perfectly.